# Typescript: Cannot find name 'DhImportKeyParams'

Tags: typescript

In a project, I am working with a third-party library that was written using Typescript 3.7. Back then, Typescript's 'lib' [included](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.7/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L4458) an interface called `DhImportKeyParams`. My project is using Typescript 4.6: `DhImportKeyParams` has since been removed. When I compile, I get the error "Cannot find name 'DhImportKeyParams'": specifically when testing. It is triggered by the definition of an interface in my third-party library's `.d.ts` file, in this interface:

```
export interface CryptoScheme {
    genAlg: Pbkdf2Params | AesKeyGenParams | HmacKeyGenParams;
    alg: string | RsaHashedImportParams | EcKeyImportParams | HmacImportParams | DhImportKeyParams | any;
    encrypt(key: CryptoKey, plaintext: string): PromiseLike<EncryptedObject>;
    decrypt(key: CryptoKey, obj: EncryptedObject): PromiseLike<string>;
}
```

How do I redefine `DhImportKeyParams` for Typescript in such a way that it will know how to deal with my third party's interface?

I tried creating a `typings.d.ts` file with the following:

```
declare interface DhImportKeyParams extends Algorithm {
    generator: Uint8Array;
    prime: Uint8Array;
}
```

Then I added the file to the references in `tsconfig.json`'s `typeRoots`:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ],
```

Testing uses `tsconfig.spec.json`, which `"extends": "../../tsconfig.json"`, but I still get the error "Cannot find name 'DhImportKeyParams'".

How do I give Typescript the missing interface in such a way that the third party can compile?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the interface declaration available globally with:

```
declare global {
  interface DhImportKeyParams extends Algorithm {
    generator: Uint8Array;
    prime: Uint8Array;
  }
}
```

You may need to add this at the end to force the file to be treated as a module declaration by exporting *something*

```
// Resolve the following error by making this a module declaration
//   Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.(2669)
export type {};
```

[See working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cxs7sj?file=index.ts,global.d.ts)